# Extracting and redirecting MP3 file with rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Attempting to extract an MP3 file from a URL and repoint it elsewhere. Example:

```
https://www.trustinsights.ai/podcast-download/1443/in-ear-insights-public-speaking-tips-and-tricks.mp3?ref=download
```

Should become:

```
http://traffic.libsyn.com/inearinsights/in-ear-insights-public-speaking-tips-and-tricks.mp3
```

I've written this Rewriterule (and rewrite engine is on) and it works in regex101, but so far does nothing in apache's htaccess:

```
RewriteRule [^/\\&\?]+\.\mp3(?=([\?&].*$|$)) http://traffic.libsyn.com/inearinsights/$1 [R]
```

What am I doing wrong?

For context, the full section of my htaccess rewrite is:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule [^/\\&\?]+\.\mp3(?=([\?&].*$|$)) http://traffic.libsyn.com/inearinsights/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong regex pattern to test the `mp3` Uri. You should be using `^/?podcast-download/1443/(.+\.mp3)$`

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?podcast-download/1443/(.+\.mp3)$ http://traffic.libsyn.com/inearinsights/$1?  [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks - the challenge is that the number is the post ID, which means it varies. It won't be the same from post to post.

Comment: In that case you can use `^/?podcast-download/\d+/(.+\.mp3)$`